# GIT SSH keys gets "forgotten" the next day, sometimes

Tags: ssh, git, ssh-keys, azure-devops

We use DevOps as git repository and I use Git GUI to generate an SSH key.

I've used DevOps months without any issues, but as of recently, I've started to notice that my SSH key get's invalidated or forgotten after a few days.

Usually I can keep using my key for 1 to 3 days, after which I need to regenerate a new key and add it do DevOps. After generating new keys I *do not* need to refresh the terminal.

This is quite frustrating to do every time.

This is the error I get when I have to generate a new one:
[image]

This is how I generate a new key:
[image] [image]

Our system administrator is not familiar with Git unfortunately, but it might be caused by a change made in our Active Directory.

Comment: Do you lose the key _locally_? That is, does the generated id_rsa file disappear? Or does the key just start getting rejected by the server?

Comment: @user1686, that's a good one. I'll have to check that once it starts to occur again. Thanks for the suggestion to check whether the id_rsa file is deleted or not.